# Swift - No aparece la opción Add Missing Constraints

Tags: swift

Soy nuevo en este lenguaje.
En el proyecto aún no he hecho nada, solamente he añadido un botón en el `View Controller` y al pulsarlo para añadir los layouts, no me aparece para poder marcar lo opción de `Add Missing Constraints` como se ve en la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿A qué se debe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probaste poner primero los constraint?, supuestamente cuando tu objeto ya esta bien colocado Xcode quita esa función, ahora por ejemplo en la foto que pongo a continuación...como puedes ver coloque unos contraint.. tamaño del botón y la colocación a partir de la posición Y.. que es el Frame superior... [image]

como puedes ver me aparecen las opciones porque aun le faltan contraints(faltantes o missing) ya solo falta presionar para solucionar ese problema que sería en mi caso, centrarlo... espero te sirva de ayuda.. saludos!

Comment: Era eso, gracias.

Comment: para ayudarnos estamos! saludos!